# How can I crate a Dataframe from a csv file within a zip?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv

I have a url which has a zip file, and within that zip there is a [***`geojson`***](https://geojson.org/) file. I want to create a dataframe using [***`geopandas`***](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) without download the file to my system.

The zip file has two files, and I want to choose a specific one

The url is [this](https://datosabiertos.bogota.gov.co/dataset/e812efbe-acc3-4e70-9bfc-30fd2134afdd/resource/efb4e03d-173e-42b2-b35a-f10d6d610df2/download/predios_csv_1020.zip).

Comment: Have you had a look at https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html ?

Comment: You have to download a file from a server in order to access its contents. That's just how it works.